# Using Snap with Ubuntu on WSL

Tags: snap, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Whenever I try to do almost anything involving snap on the Windows 10 session of Ubuntu, I get this:

```
> sudo snap install htop
```

> `error: cannot communicate with server: Post http://localhost/v2/snaps: dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: no such file or directory`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

snaps use snapd which requires systemd which is not available under WSL.

https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/windows-subsystem-for-linux/216

Comment: An absolutely correct (and succinct) answer.  For those wanting more (perhaps *too much* ) information on Systemd support in WSL, see my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1379567/1165986).

Comment: Sept. 2022 update: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/systemd-support-is-now-available-in-wsl/ but (as of time of writing this comment) does still seem to be a bit buggy