# Snapd service error: cannot communicate with server

Tags: software-installation, snap, services, 20.04

If I run any snap command it fails.

I found out that snapd service is not running. I tried to start it but this error showed up

```
Job for snapd.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status snapd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

I ran `journalctl -xe` and this is the output أبريل 29 03:15:09 Ryok

```
snap-failure[48189]: error: snapd failed: exit status 1 أبريل 29 03:15:09 Ryok systemd[1]: snapd.failure.service: Main process exited,
>
-- Subject: Unit process exited
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- An ExecStart= process belonging to unit snapd.failure.service has exited.
-- 
-- The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1. أبريل 29 03:15:09 Ryok systemd[1]: snapd.failure.service: Failed with result 'e>
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- The unit snapd.failure.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'e> أبريل 29 03:15:09 Ryok systemd[1]: Failed to start Failure handling of the snap>
-- Subject: A start job for unit snapd.failure.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit snapd.failure.service has finished with a failure.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 14440 and the job result is failed.
```

if i try for example

```
snap install postman
```

this error is thrown

```
error: cannot communicate with server: Post http://localhost/v2/snaps/postman: dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: connection refused
```

Snap version

```
snap    2.44.3+20.04
snapd   unavailable 
series  -
```

OS : Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

I tried reinstalling it and uninstalling then installing but it didn't work. I read a lot about it but no solution seemed to solve the problem.

Thanks for your time

Comment: Maybe you can check if your filesystem containing your `.snap` files is full (mine was full) : `df -Th /var/lib/snapd/snaps/`

Answer (score 1):

I think it is probably the same issue as, here due to a system not including snapd,

[Using Snap with Ubuntu on WSL](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1077820/using-snap-with-ubuntu-on-wsl)

seems very hard to fix.